# Неправильный скроллинг во фрагменте

Tags: android, xml, design

Какая-то ошибка в разметке, но не понимаю где. Сам фрагмент не хочет скроллиться, а скроллится только обведенный в рамку кусок. Как правильно сделать, чтобы скроллилось нормально, как обычная страница?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Видео](https://yadi.sk/i/ToFiUJEwjIM-wA)

fragment.xml

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@color/white">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="400dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/img" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Имя Фамилия"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tablayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                    android:id="@+id/tabChats"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Chats" />

                <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                    android:id="@+id/tabStatus"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Status" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewPager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Код фрагмента, который грузится в ViewPage

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

Comment: довольно интересная разметка у вас получается)) можно попробовать разместить в scrollView может поможет, а почему вы не попробовали создать все то что есть в двух макетах, в одном?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko просто файл "profile.xml" довольно сложный для чтения, поэтому и вынес (здесь просто удалил весь лишний код - на работоспособность это никак не повлияло). Пробовал ScrollView – результат тот же – RecycleView прокручивается в маленьком окошке

Comment: не очень понятно, как это все в куче у вас работает, по логике, картинка должна быть недвижимой, как и вкладки, просто получается что вы две разметки разместили друг над другом, но не даете им возможности прокручиваться, для этого я предлагаю попробовать scrollView использовать

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko отредактировал вопрос. Сделал все вместе эффект тот же.

Comment: а если все сделать так как вы делали вначале, только потом в главной разметке вместо вызова двух разметок поместить там разметки из тех двух файлов и потом не главный layout делать scrollview а то что внутри, а наружный пусть будет linear

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko грубо говоря обернуть все это в Linear? Не помогает. Добавил еще видео в вопрос, если интересно

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89901/discussion-between-andrew-goroshko-and--).

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте в tablayout_profile.xml android:layout_height="wrap_content"
А в profile наоборот все по match_parent

Comment: Пробовал – не помогает